# How do I 'apply' Auto Mirror to get a full mesh?

Tags: mirror

I have built a mesh with Auto Mirror.

I now want to add some features that dont mirror.

What I was hoping for was a button that said "apply" that applied the mirroring permenantly and gave a full mesh.

Is this possible?

Comment: There should be an apply mirror option under the (number panel) tools menu where you enabled auto-mirror.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett you sir are a legend.